# Python script denied in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I have a folder on my desktop that contains my script and when I run it in the pycharm ide it works perfectly but when I try to run from the terminal I get  `/Users/neelmukherjee/Desktop/budgeter/product_price.py: Permission denied`

I'm not quite sure as to why this is happening

I tried using `ls -al` to check the permissions and for some reason, the file is labelled as
`drwx------@  33 neelmukherjee  staff      1056 26 Aug 09:03 Desktop`
I'm assuming this means that I should run this file as an admin. But how exactly can I do that?

My goal is to run my script from the terminal successfully and that may be possible by running it as an admin how should I do that?

Comment: That appears to be the permissions on your Desktop folder, not the script. Try `ls -l /Users/neelmukherjee/Desktop/budgeter/product_price.py`

Comment: what exactly did you type in the terminal to run the script?

Comment: I tried running the command @GordonDavisson however i just ended up with ```-rw-r--r--@ 1 neelmukherjee  staff  395 25 Aug 22:24 /Users/neelmukherjee/Desktop/budgeter/product_price.py```

Comment: @jmh I used ```sudo python3 product_price.py```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to figure it out. I had to use

`chmod +x` to help make it executable first.

`chmod +x /Users/neelmukherjee/Desktop/budgeter/product_price.py`
and the run `/Users/neelmukherjee/Desktop/budgeter/product_price.py`